# Unmask jquery maskmoney automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem

```
<input type="text"  style="text-align:right" id="txt1"  name="txt1" onKeyUp="sum();" />
<div id="tagihan">
    <?php echo $row['spp']; ?>
</div>
<div id="txt3"></div>
```

and sum function

```
function sum() {
    var one = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var two = document.getElementById('tagihan').innerHTML;
    var result = parseInt(one) - parseInt(two);
    document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = result;
}
```

I am using jQuery mask money to format "txt1". The problem is when I am trying to do math the result in "txt3" is = nan

I have tried this but still nan

```
function sum() {    
    var one = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var num = $(one).maskMoney('unmasked')[0];
    var two = document.getElementById('tagihan').innerHTML;
    //var txtSecondNumberValue = '<?php echo $row['spp']; ?>';

    var result = parseInt(num) - parseInt(two);
    document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: change the `var one = document.getElementById('txt1')` like this

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the mask use :

```
$('#txt3').maskMoney('destroy');
```

also you are grabbing that value in jquery not the element itself, change :

```
$(one)
```

to :

```
  $('#txt1')
```